# How would I enable the Evaluate in place item of the Evaluate menu?

Tags: notebooks

I would like to be able to suppress multiple outputs when a cell is evaluated.  Is there a way to enable the "Evaluate in place" menu item of the Evaluate menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Evaluate in Place" evaluates the selected code and replaces it with the result.  It can be used when there is some text (code) selected.

I do not understand why you mean by "suppress multiple outputs when a cell is evaluated". Use `;` after an input to suppress output.

Comment: Thanks most kindly for the reply - I have it now.  I am also using SaveDefinitions->True for Manipulate commands.  This and the combination of semi-colon keep Mathematica from producing multiple instances of output when the notebook is next opened and evaluated.